# Multiple entries into Ireland on different visas

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, ireland, visa-free-entry, japanese-citizens

I have a friend who wants to come and visit Ireland in July this year (2023) for travel purposes, but they were in Ireland on a student visa from September 2022 to April 2023. They are from Japan. So they usually do not need a visa to visit Ireland.

Is it possible to enter Ireland again in the same year for different purposes? I.e. even though they were here on a student visa earlier in the year, will they be able to enter again to visit without a visa?

Comment: How long is your friend planning to stay? What ties to Japan does your friend have? In theory the answer to your question is “yes”, however typically they should be prepared to explain the purpose of their trip (possibly including *why* they are returning so soon) and show proof of sufficient funds and onward/return travel

Comment: They are only planning on visiting for 2 weeks. And they are currently university student in Japan with a year left, and have family in Japan. So that should be sufficient evidence that they will return.